How can I get the left edge as the label of pandas.cut?
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'high': [110, 110, 101, 101, 115, 300],
    }
)

And this is the expected output. Column bin should be created:
   high  bin
0   110  105.0
1   110  105.0
2   101  100.0
3   101  100.0
4   115  111.0
5   300  220.0

Basically bin is created by using pd.cut:
import numpy as np    
evaluation_bins = [100, 105, 111, 120, 220, np.inf]    
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['high'], bins=evaluation_bins, include_lowest=True, right=False)

This gives me the category itself but I want the left edge as the output.
Honestly there was not much I could try to do. I could get the dtypes of df by df.dtypes but I don't know how to continue.

Pass evaluation_bins to labels inside pd.cut, without the final edge (np.inf):
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['high'], bins=evaluation_bins, labels=evaluation_bins[:-1], 
                   include_lowest=True, right=False)

Output:
   high  bin
0   110  105
1   110  105
2   101  100
3   101  100
4   115  111
5   300  220


you can modify the pd.cut function by setting include_lowest=True and right=False then use apply(lambda x: x.left)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'high': [110, 110, 101, 101, 115, 300],
    }
)

evaluation_bins = [100, 105, 111, 120, 220, np.inf]
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['high'], bins=evaluation_bins, include_lowest=True, right=False)
df['bin'] = df['bin'].apply(lambda x: x.left)

print(df)

output:
   high    bin
0   110  105.0
1   110  105.0
2   101  100.0
3   101  100.0
4   115  111.0
5   300  220.0


Most efficient for Huge datasets :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'high': [110, 110, 101, 101, 115, 300],
    }
)

# Define the bins
bins = np.array([100, 105, 111, 220])

# Convert the high values to a numpy array
high = df['high'].to_numpy()

# Step 1: Create a full comparison matrix
comparison_matrix = bins <= high[:, None]
print('comparison_matrix :')
print(comparison_matrix)
'''
comparison_matrix :
[[ True  True False False]
 [ True  True False False]
 [ True False False False]
 [ True False False False]
 [ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True]]
'''
# Step 2: Apply the mask and replace False values with NaN 
masked_bins = np.where(comparison_matrix, bins, np.nan)
print('masked_bins :')
print(masked_bins)
'''
masked_bins :

[[100. 105.  nan  nan]
 [100. 105.  nan  nan]
 [100.  nan  nan  nan]
 [100.  nan  nan  nan]
 [100. 105. 111.  nan]
 [100. 105. 111. 220.]]
'''
# Step 3: Find the maximum value in each row, ignoring NaNs
bin_values = np.nanmax(masked_bins, axis=1)
print('bin_values :')
print(bin_values)
'''
bin_values :
[105. 105. 100. 100. 111. 220.]
'''
# Step 4: Assign the calculated bin values back to the DataFrame
df['bin'] = bin_values

print(df)
'''
  high    bin
0   110  105.0
1   110  105.0
2   101  100.0
3   101  100.0
4   115  111.0
5   300  220.0
'''

